# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibs.routs/com.ibs.routs.Activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**1. Al ejecutar mi aplicación me da todo este error según en mi xml**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la linea 36

Comment: Hola ALEX, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: No se puede inflar la vista del layout principal, pero agrega todo el layout como texto no como imagen para que sea visible para toda la comunidad.